# JSONPath Returning a parent element based on a child filter

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am trying to find a JSONPath expression to get the `Itemid` of every Item in a set if the `Customer == 123` but the JSONPath is escaping me.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "Item:7823yrhfjbafuuowegfuwvbsvbhjbauagwoeufgaus": {
        "Itemid": "7823yrhfjbafuuowegfuwvbsvbhjbauagwoeufgaus",
        "Customers": [{
                "Customer": 123
            },
            {
                "Customer": 456
            }
        ]
    },
    "Item:1234yrhfjbafuuowegfuwvbsvbhjbauagwoeufgdan": {
        "Itemid": "1234yrhfjbafuuowegfuwvbsvbhjbauagwoeufgdan",
        "Customers": [{
                "Customer": 123
            },
            {
                "Customer": 456
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried `$..Itemid[?($..Customers[?(@.Customer==123)])]` and a ton of variations but none of them are working for me. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with nested filters, but you'll need to use the `@` for each one. The `$` references the data root.

```
$[?@.Customers[?@.Customer==123]].Itemid
```

```
$                                // root 
 [                               // find values
  ?                              // where
   @.Customers                   // Customers
              [                  // has values
               ?                 // where
                @.Customer==123  // Customer is 123
              ]
 ]
 .Itemid                         // get Itemid
```

I haven't tested this yet (but will later), but you can try it out at https://json-everything.net/json-path.